# How does loop order affect bit manipulation for this case in C?

Tags: c, printing, bit-manipulation, decimal, bit

The code below ends up in a seemingly endless loop while printing some decimal numbers.

```
int main(){
    show(0xBADECAFU);
}

void show(unsigned a){
    unsigned pos=0;
    for(; pos<UINT_MAX; pos++)
        printf("%u", (1U<<pos) & a);
}
```

The code below actually shows the bits of the hex number. Why does the first program run improperly while the second does not?

```
int main(){
     show(0xBADECAFU);
}

void show(unsigned n){
    unsigned pos=31, count=1;
    for(; pos!=UINT_MAX; pos--, count++){
        printf("%u", n>>pos & 1U);
}
```

Comment: Have you printed UINT_MAX to see what the first loop is trying to do?

Comment: Let's see.  pos starts at 31 and counts down until it hits 4,294,967,295.  Nope, don't see a problem there at all. :)

Comment: @MarkReed, as long as underflow goes to `(unsigned)~0` that should be fine.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: good point.  I withdraw my objection. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not `UINT_MAX` bits in an `unsigned int`. There are, however, `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int)` bits.

```
/* nb: this prints bits LSB first */
void show(unsigned a){
    unsigned pos=0;
    for(; pos < CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned); pos++)
        printf("%u", (1U<<pos) & a ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Consider your second case, where you loop until `pos` equals `UINT_MAX`. This will properly<sup>*</sup> print out 32 bits of `unsigned`, assuming underflow goes to `~0` and `sizeof(unsigned)` is at least 4.

Your second example could be improved slightly:

```
void show(unsigned n){
    int pos = (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned)) - 1;
    for(; pos >= 0; pos--) {
        printf("%u", (n>>pos) & 1U);
    }
}
```

<sub>* Your code which "prints" the bits was odd, and in my example I've fixed it up.</sub>

Comment: Is it improper to print out the bits themselves? IThe following is my new function
for(; pos<8*sizeof(unsigned); pos++)
    printf("%u", (1U<<pos) & a);

I still haven't made the changes u mode for the print statement. When I print i get the following

1248032012800102420480819216384327686553602621445242880209715208388608167772163355443201342177280000

What stupid thing am i doing this time :P

Comment: `%u` means print out an unsigned integer. If you print out bit 7 being set (or `1<<7` in your case), you're actually printing out `2**7` or 128 rather than 1 or 0 as you likely intended.

Comment: why does the first example i used in the OP output it as 1 or 0's?

Comment: Because you're performing a bitwise-AND against 1. The answer will be either 0 or 1. In the other instance you're doing a bitwise-AND with `1<<pos` and `a`, meaning your answers will be `1<<pos` or 0.

Comment: OH so the variable "a" by itself isn't looked at in its binary format unless you use some sort of bit-wise operator? Its automatically converted to decimal correct?

Comment: `a` is stored as an unsigned binary 32-bit number in this case, `%u` prints an unsigned 32-bit number as a decimal.

Answer (score 2):

UINT_MAX is the maximum value which can be stored in an unsigned int variable. It is not directly related to the number of bits.

Your first loop is incrementing over a huge number of ints.

Your second loop is decrementing from 31 to ??? (unsigned, so what happens when you decrement 0? - looks like you are lucky and 0-1 = UINT_MAX)

Comment: Well, actually, it *is* directly related to the number of bits.  :)  This version would work:  unsigned pos=1;
    for(; pos<UINT_MAX; pos<<=1)
        printf("%u", pos & a);

Comment: Yeah, but not directly as in UINT_MAX=32, which is what the OP seemed to think ;-). Better to use 8*sizeof(unsigned).

Comment: @John3136 wraparound on unsigned integers is well-defined.

Comment: @MarkReed that will keep wrapping around, never reaching `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.

I think the problem with the first one is that `(1U<<pos)` invokes undefined behavior if `pos >= (sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT)`.  In such cases, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants.  It might assume that you would *never* create such a situation, hence `pos` must *always* be `< (sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT) < UINT_MAX`, hence the loop condition can be optimized away.  Unfortunately, this "optimization" leaves you with an infinite loop.

Comment: Of course, the first one doesn't really do what you want to do anyway.  The above is just a possible explanation for the "seemingly endless loop."